# WiX Toolset - issues running cmd in Custom Action

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to add a custom action that will delete files from the installation folder using the following code:

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallService" Return="check" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand='cmd.exe /C del /s /q "[INSTALLFOLDER]"'/>
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
          <Custom Action="InstallService" Before ="InstallFiles">NOT Installed AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This works on some computers but fails on others showing a message

> A program required for install to complete could not be run.

And in the installation logs I see

> Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor

Any idea why this might happen or how to make it work?

Comment: I'm not a Wix expert. But I would: 1. Check your log file and verify that [INSTALLFOLDER] is being resolved correctly since it's running in a deferred context. 2. Try specifying the full path to cmd.exe in case a machine has an incorrect environment variable setup 3. You do realise you're running this BEFORE you install any files during the installation?

Comment: I would recommend moving away from direct 'cmd' execution and instead use the Wix "Quiet Execution Custom Action" extension - https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html. This way your action will log to the msi log file.